# How to make view/camera follow Uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit

Im making a scene for my game. Right now im working for IPhone 5-5s-5c screens. The scene is bigger than the normal IPhone 5-5s-5c`s screen widths so the simulated size is freeform.

Now, your supposed to move this image between obstacles. and the view/ camera is supposed to follow the uiimageview.

Here is some code on how i move the image

```
    -(IBAction)left { goLeft = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(goLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; if (goLeft == nil) { goLeft = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(goLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; }

}

-(IBAction)stopLeft { [goLeft invalidate]; goLeft = nil;
}



-(void)goLeft { ball2.center = CGPointMake(ball2.center.x -3.5, ball2.center.y);{

 // left is connected to touch down 
// stopLeft is connected to Touch up inside
// Thanks for any help :)
```

Answer (score 0):

@cilus-stian The previous version of your question was tagged as SpriteKit, so I'll suppose you use SpriteKit. If you don't use it, please let me know, and I'll delete my answer which becomes irrelevant.

So what you want is your camera to follow your image (ball2).

You can simply create a SKCameraNode which does exactly what you want (sorry I don't know the Objc syntax) :

```
// Declare your camera
var camera: SKCameraNode = SKCameraNode()

// Add it to your scene (didMoveToView or init)
self.camera = camera

// In the update() function
self.camera.position = ball2.position
```

More details about [SKCameraNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCameraNode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015250)

Also, not sure how/why you use UIImageView, but maybe you should consider using SKSpriteNode to display your ball

Comment: Thanks so much for quick respond! Im writing my game in objective c,  and in gameviewcontroller.h & m could you show me how?:)

Comment: I think you lack some basics about how SpriteKit works. I suggest you read a few docs/tutorials first ;) Check out [this one](https://www.raywenderlich.com/51068/how-to-make-a-game-like-space-invaders-with-sprite-kit-tutorial-part-1). It will show you how to use spriteKit in objective-c. Then you will be able to easily integrate what I gave you in your code

Comment: I understand. But "var" doesnt exist in objective c ? Could you show me an example on how you would do this and where to put it? Sorry for asking so much..

Comment: I said in my answer that I don't know the objective-C syntax ;) It's just declaring a variable, probably something like @property(nonatomic) SKCameraNode camera = [SKCameraNode init]. Not sure about init, but you can use xcode autocompletion to look for the right initializer ;)

Comment: Hm ok i will try! Thanks :)

Comment: I have still not figured out how to do it :(